# Submit a form using a link and pass a post variable

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

Hi I want to use an anchor tag to submit a form. However the only problem is that my form had an input button (now replaced by anchor tag) that passed a post variable so that in my php script I could check to see if that post variable was set. How can I achieve this same technique using an achor tag? Here is what I have tried:

FORM USING AN INPUT BUTTON (old):

```
<form method="post" action="delete.php" onsubmit="return confirm('Do you really want to delete?');">
<input class="delbtn" name="deleteuser" type="submit" value="Delete"/>
</form>
```

FORM USING ANCHOR TAG INSTEAD OF INPUT SUBMIT (new):

```
<form id="delform" method="post" action="delete.php" onsubmit="return confirm('Do you really want to delete?');">
<a href="javascript:void();" onclick="document.getElementById('delform').onsubmit();" class="delbtn" >Delete</a>
</form>
```

In my php class I am checking to see if the form was submitted using the post variable from the input button ("deleteuser"). However how can I do the same using an anchor tag?

Comment: If you're using an anchor tag to submit the form, you'll need to change your PHP script to use $_GET or $_REQUEST instead of $POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've almost got it in your second try, just call [.submit()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.submit) instead of onsubmit().

```
<form id="delform" method="post" action="delete.php" onsubmit="if( confirm('Do you really want to delete?')) {this.submit();}">
<a href="javascript:void();" onclick="document.getElementById('delform').onsubmit();" class="delbtn" >Delete</a>
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="deleteuser" />
</form>
```

[Here is a JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/N6maM/1/)

Comment: But how can I pass on the name="deleteuser" bit from my original button so that my php file knows I submitted the form

Comment: Oh, add the hidden input element, i've added it to the example

Comment: And it will work just how I intend it to? And I dont need to have a value?

Comment: it does need to have a value, and you may need to adjust the script to check for a different post variable, in this example your php script would need to check $_POST['action'] == 'deleteuser'.  Looking at your  first example again you might not have to change your php if you name the hidden input deleteuser and set the value to Delete

Comment: The reason why this wont work on my form is because there are n number of forms that are created based on the number of users there are. So if each form has a hidden input where its value is deleteuser, then how will my script know which form has been submitted

Comment: put a userid hidden input?